# Custom object not available in "related to" list of a master-detail field of a custom object

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, master-detail

I am attempting to create a master-detail field on a custom object, and on step 2 in the "related to" dropdown I am looking for another custom object that I created before but unfortunately it is no where in the list.

[image]

The only things I can think that could influence this, but I'm not sure why, is that the custom object I'm looking for in this list also has a master-detail field to the `Account` object. Also there are two other custom objects that also have a relationship to this specific custom object (1 is a lookup and the other is a master-detail).

Appreciate any insight.

Comment: looks like you want to create a MD field on Account to Custom object.. I am afraid you can do this. you can't create a MD on standard object to custom object but you can create lookup and make that field required..

Comment: can you check profile permission on your custom object?

Comment: There is only 2 Master Detail Relationship allowed per object and it can have upto three custom detail levels. Each object is allowed to have one or two masters, or up to 8 details

Comment: You should check ur custom object.How many children does ur custome.object has?

Comment: There should be a limit that an object could be master up to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have 2 Master Detail relationships to a [Custom Object](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm) therefore you would either have to change one of the existing M:D relationships to a Lookup or use a Lookup in this case.

Probably the most important question here is which objects does this custom object need to inherit visibility from and do any of the other objects require things like roll up summary of the custom object's fields.

Comment: Another related detail if having to use a lookup relationship that could be helpful for someone else: http://salesforcedrive.blogspot.com/2014/04/how-to-delete-child-records-with-lookup.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to populate first the field with a look up relationship
Then change the field to master-detail